# Dropdown option cannot be selected if I put the component inside my label

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, tailwind-css

Why doesn't my `Dropdown` component work when I put it inside my `<label>` tag? The dropdown is displaying the options, but if you click on one, the selection is not working/displayed.

Any suggestions?

```
    export default function App() {
     
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="mt-10 mb-3 h-6 text-md uppercase font-bold>
            People
          </div>
          <button type="button" onClick={addInvitee}>
            +Add menu
          </button>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {invited.map(({ age, email, id, location, name }, index) => (
              <div key={id}>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5">
                  <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold">
                    Names:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={name}
                      placeholder="Names"
                      name="name"
                      onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
                    />
                  </label>
                 //other inputs with the exact same pattern
                  <label>
                    Choice:
                    <Dropdown className="w-3/5" options={CHOICE} isMulti={false} />
                  </label>
                 ...//other inputs
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

**Dropdown.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import Tag from "./Tag";

export default function Dropdown({
  className,
  style,
  options,
  styleSelect,
  defaultValue,
  isMulti = false
}) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultValue);

  const styles = {
    select: {
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: 200
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {selected && isMulti === false ? (
        <Tag
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
          styleSelect={styleSelect}
        />
      ) : (
        <Select
          className={className}
          style={styles.select}
          value={selected}
          onChange={setSelected}
          options={options}
          isMulti={isMulti}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button-forked-e7lret?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Is there a way to fix that please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe that's why, I have issues when I want send data to my backend??

Comment: @MosiaThabo can you explain that as an  answer, like you said  please ?

Comment: I apologize man, I have just been busy lately.

Comment: I have explained the issue you're having below. I hope you will find it clear enough to understand. Event Bubbles are very tricky sometimes.

Comment: did you try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly here's something important to note:
[image]

Based on this image, a console snippet from sandbox, it shows that the selection happens, but it gets cleared instantly.

What's the cause for this? Hmm.. let's take a look.

Consider this code snippet:

```html
<label>
  Press the text 
  <br /><br />
  <button onClick="console.log('button-clicked')">Button</button>
</label>
```

Here, the `<button>` is placed inside a `<label>`. Do you notice, that when you click on `press the text`, the `button`'s `onClick` gets triggered? ... But why?

Well, by default, a `<label>` is a focusable html element, and when focused, it triggers any form control element placed inside it.

**So how does this relate to your code?**

You have this line of code inside your `<Tag>` component `onClick={() => setSelected(null)}` and that's where the problem is. When you pick a selection, the `selected` gets updated and the component re-renders and displays your `<Tag>` component... but the event still bubbles up tree again until it reaches the `<label>` element. remember, at this point, it's no longer the `<Select>` component shown, but the `<Tag>` component. And guess what? the `<label>` gets focused and triggers the `<button>` inside your `<Tag>` component which clears (`setSelected(null)`) the `selected` state property. Once the `selected` is cleared, the `<Dropdown>` component re-renders and  the `<Select>` component is displayed again.

This goes on and on and on as you try to select, then the process repeats.

So, from your code... Just remove this here `onClick={() => setSelected(null)}` and you'll see it will work. So you just need to work around it on how to clear the `selected`, but I have suggested a solution below.

---

**The Solution**

In your `<Dropdown>` component, we should try and prevent the event from bubbling. So all you need to do is add the following  `onClick={e=>e.preventDefault()}` in your `<div>`

```
<div style={style} onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      {selected && isMulti === false ? (
        <Tag
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
          styleSelect={styleSelect}
        />
      ) : (
        <Select
          className={className}
          style={styles.select}
          value={selected}
          onChange={setSelected}
          options={options}
          isMulti={isMulti}
        />
      )}
    </div>
```

[Here's the original sandbox with the solution applied.](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button-forked-fure06?file=/src/Dropdown.jsx)

Comment: in this simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-agnesi-1grr0e?file=/src/App.js), you can see that now I'm not able to withdraw my selected option (choose Good and click on the cross to select  other option, then you can't). Is there a way to avoid that ??

Comment: You added the code incorrectly. See the Solution above. Don't remove `onClick={() => setSelected(null)}` ... just add `onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` in your `<Dropdown>`'s `div` element

Comment: Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button-forked-fure06?file=/src/Dropdown.jsx

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation I get it :) Maybe you can help me with this setState  [errorIssue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249899/whats-wrong-in-my-code-that-gives-me-cant-call-setstate-on-a-component-that-i)